# Drinking from a drinking fountain throughout the day

Tags: food, blessing, time, water, appliances

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18741/what-brachot-do-you-say-and-when-if-you-drink-intermittently-all-day) deals with someone who has a cup of a drink and carries it around all day long, possibly refilling it, etc. I am wondering, for someone who drinks from a drinking fountain every time he walks by it, should he make a new bracha each time he drinks? Does it matter how much time goes by between episodes? What other considerations are there?

Answer (score 1):

I heard from a student of Rabbi Yisroel Labkowski (the Rabbi is word-for-word boki in Shulchan Aruch, you start reading anything, and he can finish it) that he said there are 5 reasons in halacha why you are not allowed to drink directly from a water fountain.

I don't remember all 5, but the one I do remember is that you have to see the item you are making a Bracha on, and the water you drink from a water fountain is not the water you see when you say the Bracha.

Assuming you avoid this, or your LOR tells you it is not a problem, [the answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18761/440) there would seem to apply equally to here.

Comment: I don't know his other reasons, but that one is against an explicit Rabbeinu Yona.  He says that you make a blessing on drinking water from a river, even though the water that you will drink is not necessarily in front of you when you make the blessing. (The fact that you can drink from a river is a gemara, Rabbeinu Yonah is just explaining that the blessing is not an issue)

Comment: @YEZ, apparently others don't agree. Or I have a bad memory.

Comment: Are you thinking of the Rama in YD 116:5 ,its a sakanna to drink from a tap

Comment: I don't know who is going to disagree with the Gemara that you can drink from a river.  Rabbeinu Yonah is just explicit that a blessing isn't the problem.  Unless you have a distinction between the water not in front of you at a river vs. fountain.  If anything, at least in the fountain you know which water you will be drinking (that closest to the spout) even if you can't see it.

Comment: S it is, now, this answer basically nullifies the questions premise. But, it doesn't answer the question directly, as OP assumes that there is no problem drinking from the fountain. You have provided a link to an opinion that has the answer. I think you should edit in what that answer is or summarize what is in the link.

Comment: This may be a full or partial dupe - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18741/5275