# Does one need to have the water fountain running while reciting the blessing?

Tags: halacha, blessing, water, drinking

When one recites a blessing, the item upon which the blessing is recited must be in front of him.

The question is: if one is drinking from a water fountain, would he need to have it running while reciting the blessing, in order that the water should be in front of him, or is it enough to have the water machine in front of him, even though he can’t see the water?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40752/759

Comment: At least you should turn it on for a second before saying the blessing to make sure it's plugged in and functional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sefer vzos habracha chapter 1 page 9 he brings from R’ Scheinberg to turn on the fountain (our faucet drinking straight from there) to avoid a hefsek (like the MB 206:19) and to show that the bracha is on the water.