# Is taking an extended warm shower Bal Tashchis? Biblically?

Tags: halacha, bal-tashchit-waste

Is taking an extended warm shower for pleasure (maybe also for health (Rambam dipping in hot water is healthy (i do not remember specific source))) Bal Tashchis Diorisa?

Where can I find sources on the subject?

Possibly related: [Is runoff water from a drinking fountain a problem of Bal Tashhith?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12933/is-runoff-water-from-a-drinking-fountain-a-problem-of-bal-tashhith/12942#12942)

Comment: Why would you assume it is bal tashchis if you are using it for hanaah

Comment: @YEZ good save ;)

Comment: In your question is what are limits of "Bal Tashchis". In most places you pay for the water that you use. Also, in most cases, water is already in your water tank sitting there. It's a question of when you use it. (Yes, when it gets low, the tank must refill from the public water area, but you have no true control on when this happens.) So, if you are using water that "sits" there for personal pleasure, there is a use of SOME kind. How is the water being "wasted"? Perhaps, you can argue this if the tank were being filled while you're showering. Then, you're getting "additional" water.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer would be that it is not prohibited as "Bal Tashchis" because you are using it for something – getting hanaah.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Your point?? If you eat, cook, or use the fruit in some way, it's not bal tashchis. If you randonly cut down the fruit tree on your property, then probably, yes. If you cut it down because it's leaning towrd your house and you're afraid that a wind may knock it down, it's not bal tashchis b/c you had a valid reason for cutting it down.

Comment: It was just to say that you are allowed to use it for hanaah, but I agree with you. (edited)

Comment: Using a fruit tree to get into a city is also using it for something and getting _hanaa_ from it, yet that's the prototypical case of _bal tashchis_.

Comment: Can you explain what is the prototypical case? A little more?

Comment: @msh210 - I assume that you are referring to the verse in Devarim 21:19 which says that when you go to war against another city, you should not cut down the fruit trees. I believe that in this case, the Torah prohibits chopping it down because there is no need to do so, because you can eventually benefit from its fruit after you win the war. Perhaps, if the fruit trees were in the direct battle line and the enemy was using them to hide from your shots, you may be able to cut them down. Have to check the details, and this would be on a separate discussion, anyway.